# Vuex state not showing empty cart message using v-if & v-else

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-statements, vuex

I am trying to show the message `Cart empty` in my modal when the cart is empty. When a product is added to the cart, that message should be removed and replaced with the product.

[image]

The product being added to the modal is working, but when I delete, and the quantity is 0, the message does not show.

[image]

I am using Vuex, but when tryin to use `v-if` and `v-else` within the `v-for` loop, the `Cart empty` message does not show. Below is an example of my `MinCart.vue` modal.

```html
        <div class="modal-body" v-for="item in this.$store.state.cart">
          <div v-if="noItemsInCart">Cart empty</div>
          <div v-else>
              <div class="card mb-3 border-0">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <img :src="item.productImage" width="120px" class="align-self-center mr-3" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card-block px-2">
                            <h6 class="card-title">{{ item.productName }}</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">{{ item.productPrice | currency }}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Quantity: {{ item.productQuantity }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <div class="card-body pt-1">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                          <a @click="$store.commit('removeFromCart', item)" type="button" class="card-link-secondary small text-uppercase mr-3">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt mr-1"></i>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my computed prop:

```js
    computed: {
      noItemsInCart() {
        return this.$store.getters.cartEmpty
      }
    }
```

And finally, my `store.js` with the getter method;

```js
  state: {
    cart: cart ? JSON.parse(cart) : [], 
  },

  getters: {
    cartEmpty: state => {
      let qty = 0;
      state.cart.filter((item) => {
        qty = item.productQuantity
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Vuex getter doesn't return anything, so it's always falsy, which makes the computed prop (`noItemsInCart`) always truthy.

But your getter also isn't using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) correctly. The filter is assigning `qty` instead of comparing it, and the `filter` callback returns nothing.

I'm guessing you were trying to count the items in the cart by checking `productQuantity` of each item. That would be done with [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
{
  getters: {
    // find any item that has a positive `productQuantity` value
    cartEmpty: state => state.cart.some(item => item.productQuantity > 0)
  }
}
```

Also, your template should move the `v-for` loop into the `v-else` block. Otherwise, an empty cart will prevent the `v-if` block from rendering (thus no `Cart empty` message):

```html
<div v-if="noItemsInCart">Cart empty</div>
<div v-else class="modal-body" v-for="item in this.$store.state.cart">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @tony19 thanks for taking the time to respond, was great feedback that i have been able to use. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need getter in this case. You just need to return in computed something like this:

```js
computed: {
  isEmptyCart() {
    return Boolean(~this.$store.state.cart.length); // or use compare ...length > 0
  }.
}
```

Or more beautiful example with `mapState`:

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    cart: ({ cart }) => cart; // don't use this.$store.state.cart in template
    isEmptyCart: ({ cart }) => Boolean(~cart.length),
  }),
}
```